# Install firefox old version - Linux machine - Selenium tests fail for firefox version

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, version, automated-tests

I'm running some Selenium GUI tests (headless) on a Linux server and the browser is Firefox. Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

I installed FireFox version using **yum** and getting an error message as Selenium tests failed. Firefox installed version via yum is: 17.0.9 version.

The error message is given below. It seems like the Selenium webdriver/java/jar version that we are using in many projects (2.39.0) has a dependency on Firefox, that it's not compatible with later versions of Firefox > 26. Thus, If I can somehow install Firefox version 26 or between 24 - 26, my tests will work. Selenium-java 2.39.0 version supports upto FIREFOX browser 26 and it seems like the one "yum" installed is too lower version.

**Questions:**

1. From where can I download Firefox version 26
2. How can I install Firefox version 26 using "yum" command
3. How can I remove the existing latest version of Firefox from my Linux machine.

**Error message highlight:**

*Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port*
**OR**
*Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1*

**Full Error message:**

```
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: Error: no display specified Error: no display specified Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38' System info: host: 'linuxdevserver12', ip: '10.112.6.211', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.18-348.16.1.el5', java.version: '1.7.0_40' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'linuxdevserver12', ip: '10.112.6.211', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.18-348.16.1.el5', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:195)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
at com.thc.ids.application.seleniumcommon.SCBaseTest.setupSimpleBrowser(SCBaseTest.java:1045)
at com.thc.ids.application.seleniumcommon.SCBaseTest.access$100(SCBaseTest.java:54)
at com.thc.ids.application.seleniumcommon.SCBaseTest$1.setUp(SCBaseTest.java:219)
at junit.extensions.TestSetup$1.protect(TestSetup.java:22)
at junit.extensions.TestSetup.run(TestSetup.java:27)
at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:260)
at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:71)
at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:86)
at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy:37)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com.thc.ids.gradle.ThidsTestSeleniumTask.performTest(ThidsTestSeleniumTask.groovy:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
at com.thc.ids.gradle.ThidsTestSeleniumTask_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for:

1. https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/26.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/ 
   (after releases, specify your xx.x version, OS type/bit type and language) and you'll find 
   .tar.bz2 format bundle.

BUT,
after *tar -xvf* and having this version of firefox as */production/firefox* folder, when I'm running: **./firefox -version**, I'm getting an error. ENV variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is set to: */production/firefox:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib*

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /production/firefox/libxul.so:
libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Another thing. I managed to resolve the error message as it was due to **NO DISPLAY**. I installed "**xvfb**" plugin in Jenkins and enabled it. Now, I'm not getting NO DISPLAY error but a different one. The following error is not coming now atleast.

```
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: Error: no display specified Error: no display specified
```

Answer 2: I don't think I can do this. I have to use rpm (which gives other installation issues).

Answer 3: yum erase firefox

The whole purpose for this post was to run Selenium tests on a Linux machine (Headless).

To resolve that issue, all I did was to install "Xvfb" plugin in Jenkins. Configured it in the Jenkins job (which was running the tests/calling the tests). I checked the boxes for "Enable Xvfb", Timeout (5) seconds, Log Xvfb. **DO NOT** check/tick the box for "Let Xvfb choose the display #" or you'll get the following error.

In the Jenkins log:
You'll see .. instead of calling the following (valid) command

```
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :3 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /production/jenkinsAKS/2014-10-30_13-56-051887436837486829115xvfb
```

somehow when the check box for "Let Xvfb choose the display".. is checked, it sometimes doesn't work and gives the command as given below (with a usage info for Xvfb). PS "-displayfd 2 " argument which is not correct:

```
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /production/jenkinsAKS/2014-10-30_13-56-051887436837486829115xvfb
```

So, uncheck Let Xvfb choose display box and you'll be fine (as then it'll use :SomeNumber in arguments while calling Xvfb command). Now, Selenium GUI tests are running fine no worries about which version of firefox as the existing 17.0.9 (firefox version installed by YUM worked fine).